# Toggling assert testing

Tags: c, testing, assert

I have two source files: one I want to test via asserts, the second containing the asserts.

My problem is that I do not want the testing to be run each time the program itself is run, so is there a way to toggle assert testing on or off depending on a makefile argument?

Or will I have to create another source file, containing both the code I want to test and the assert testing itself?

Answer (score 0):

`man 3 assert` says

> If  the  macro  NDEBUG is defined at the moment <assert.h> was last
> included, the macro assert() generates no code, and hence does
> nothing at all.

`gcc ... -DNDEBUG` is intended for a release build, and will not do anything in `assert()`.

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is that I do not want the testing to be run each time the
> program itself is run

If only the second file you mention contains the assert statements, why would the test code be run when you run the program?

Here is a typical way to divide the code for a module *Foo* containing a function *Bar* and its unit test:

Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

int Foo_Bar(int i);

#endif
```

Foo.c

```
#include "Foo.h"

int Foo_Bar(int i)
{
    /*to be implemented*/
    return -1;
}
```

FooTest.c

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include <assert.h>

int main(void)
{
    assert(Foo_Bar(0) == 0);
    return 0;
}
```

myprog.c

```
#include "Foo.h"

int main(void)
{
    int bar = Foo_Bar(0);
    /*...*/
    return 0;
}
```